# ClassNotFoundException on spring beans inside jboss fuse camel application

Tags: spring, jboss, jboss6.x, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to create a spring-based fuse integration making external soap calls.

Using the code in a standalone java apps works fine but when importing it in my Fuse Integration project, I have the following error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean not found by org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-ws-core [439]
```

I don't know where to start to debug this.

Here are relevant part of my pom:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>myBundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>Empty Camel Spring Example [myBundle]</Bundle-Name>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                    <Import-Package>*,org.springframework.beans.factory</Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I also double-checked that spring components are loaded in fuse:
[image]

At this point, I just don't know what to do to get this working!
Many thanks for your help !

**edit**:
Checking by bundles imports shows:
[image]
Which tends to confirm that

> org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean

is loaded !

Comment: I would bet it's related to wrong camel-spring-ws version. E.g. you are using version 1.0.0 in your project and it has *.class, however fuse uses it's own bundle with 2.0.0 version and there is no such class.

Comment: any idea of how could I troubleshoot this ?

Comment: sure, just use the same jar version as fuse uses.(2.17.0.redhat-630187)

Comment: it's the version I use for camel components! so I don't understand where would be this version mismatch :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's the following bug here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-6856 which is already fixed and will be made available through 6.3.0 R4 (which is due to be released these days).

Since you are using Fuse 6.3 187 I'd highly recommend to follow their patch cycle and apply the updates regularly (schedule can be seen here:  https://access.redhat.com/articles/2939351).

If you are brave, you can also play around with the internal builds (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/ea/org/jboss/fuse/jboss-fuse-karaf/6.3.0.redhat-280/), however these versions won't be supported unless they are part of an official patch release.